# How to disable a network enabled plugin on all sites, excepting on one?

Tags: multisite

I would like use a plugin only on my network home site.
Here is the converse of my question: [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/how-to-disable-a-network-enabled-plugin-for-just-one-site)

There is the solution this:

```
add_filter('site_option_active_sitewide_plugins', 'modify_sitewide_plugins');

function modify_sitewide_plugins($value) {
    global $current_blog;

    if( $current_blog->blog_id == 2 ) {
        unset($value['akismet/akismet.php']);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

How to modify this code, that the $value plugin should be disabled on every subsites (automatically also on subsequent sites), expect on the $current_blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code is for one site, and you want it to be for all except one. You need to change the **==** part to **!=** in order to do this. This way instead of running the code inside the *if* on the site with ID 2, it will run on all sites except the one with ID 2.

But I don't know why you would do this, since you can activate a plugin only on one site by just activating it from its dashboard (you do not need to network activate it).

Comment: Than I asked this question I thought this is the best way to the solution, but easier exchange the user (avatar scr, username links) references in admin-bar.php (and the comments.php in current theme directory).